# How to make my CodeChef solution code faster?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner currently in first semester. I have been practising on Code Chef and am stuck at this problem. They are asking to reduce the execution time of my code. The problem goes as follows:

> Meliodas and Ban are fighting over chocolates. Meliodas has X chocolates, while Ban has Y. Whoever has lesser number of chocolates eats as many chocolates as he has from the other's collection. This eatfest war continues till either they have the same number of chocolates, or at least one of them is left with no chocolates.
> Can you help Elizabeth predict the total no of chocolates they'll be left with at the end of their war?
>
> Input:
> First line will contain T, number of testcases. Then the testcases follow.
> Each testcase contains of a single line of input, which contains two integers X,Y, the no of chocolates Meliodas and Ban have, respectively.
>
> Output:
> For each testcase, output in a single line the no of chocolates that remain after Ban and Meliodas stop fighting.

Sample Input:

```
3
5 3
10 10
4 8
```

Sample Output:

```
2
20
8
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    unsigned int t,B,M;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>M>>B;
        if(B==M)
        {
            cout<<B+M<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=1;B!=M;i++)
            {
                if(B>M)
                B=B-M;
                else
                M=M-B;
            }
            cout<<M+B<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you get a TLE you  probably need to rethink your algorithm. Maybe there is some math trick that you can use to calculate the answer without looping. I don't know. I don't concentrate on these math word problems in over 25 years.

Comment: It seems most such sites relies on trickery for its assignments, the two most common being to figure out a way to calculate results instead of using loops, and to use so-called dynamic programming which essentially caches earlier calculations to reduce the number of loops. In general, trickery is not something you should learn, it really won't make you a better programmer. And such sites also won't make you a better programmer, all they seem to "teach" are bad habits and bad code. Learn programming, C++ and good habits properly first, then use such sites to train your existing knowledge.

Comment: You don't check in the loop if either `B` or `M` becomes 0, and your loop never ends. That's because e.g. for `B = 5` and `M = 0` you will try to subtract 0 from 5 until B is equal M, and B will never be equal M, because you subtract 0 over and over

Comment: prefer signed integer arithmetic over non-signed arithmetic. The latter can give issues.

Comment: How are you calculating the excecution time?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't fully agree: they often make you think about the problem and the underlying solution. Instead of just brute forcing it. After that somebody perhaps better understands why we have standardized algorithms.

Comment: Why is dynamic programming "so called?" It's a legitimate programming practice, taught in universities.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Can you please tell me how to proceed further??

Comment: @SomnathChoudhury I guess the shortest is to replace `B!=M` with `B!=M && B>0 && M>0`

Comment: @SomnathChoudhury https://godbolt.org/z/Pv18c3TPT

Comment: Hint: if B > M, how many times can you take M from B? Do you need a loop to figure it out? Do you need a loop to figure out how much there is left afterwards?

Comment: @JHBonarius: I agree with you that a programmer should always wonder if their algo is *reasonably* fast before coding it. But most of the time the questions of those kind of sites have no real world use cases. And choosing the proper algo is not really a beginner programmer question.  More exactly there is a time to *analyze* a problem and choose how it should be solved in terms of tools, libraries and algorithms. And then a time to code it in a language. If the programmer has to revamp a general algo, it is a serious hint that the previous operation was skipped...

Comment: ... And if it is skipped for a real world question, chances are that the final result will not meet the initial requirement. Only slightly more than 30 years of various experiences let me say that...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `B`and `M`are different from 0, this algorithm corresponds to one version of the Euclidean algorithm. Therefore, you can simply:

```
std::cout << 2 * std::gcd(B, M) << "\n";
```

If at least one of the quantity is equal to 0, then just print `B + M`.

Answer (score 0):

After realizing that your code was correct, I wondered where could be any algorithmic improvement. And I realized that *eating as many chocolate from the peer as one has* was in fact close to a modulo operation. If both number are close, a minus operation could be slightly faster than a modulo one, but if one number is high, while the other is 1, you immediately get it instead of looping a great number of times...

The key to prevent stupid errors is to realize that if a modulo is 0, that means that the high number is a multiple of the small one and we must stop immediately writing twice the lower value.

And care should be taken that if one of the initial counts are 0, the total number will never change.

So the outer loop should become:

```
    if(B==M || B == 0 || M == 0)
    {
        cout<<B+M<<"\0";
    }
    else {
        for (;;) {
            if (M < B) {
                B = B % M;
                if (B == 0) {
                    cout << M * 2 << '\n';
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                M = M % B;
                if (M == 0) {
                    cout << B * 2 << '\n';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

Note: no infinite loop is possible here because a modulo ensures that  for example is `M > B > 0' after` M = M % B`you will have`B > M >= 0`and as the case`== 0` is explicitely handled the number of loops cannot be higher than the lower number.

Comment: This loops infinitely just like the original code.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I have rewritten my answer after realizing that I missed the time limit point. But a side effect is that your comment is now irrelevant...

Comment: Your new code tries to divide by zero.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I wrongly assumed that the initial values were > 0. Fixed. Anyway this will never be a good answer and will probably be deleted...